# I need a code to display images dynamically

Tags: java, android, xml

I am new to Android so I have a query about displaying the images

[image]

I have created a button in the `main.xml` file which is working correctly but it shows only one image. I want all the images to be displayed one by one such that I can swipe to left hand side and check all the images which are in the drawable folder shown on the left hand side

the code which I have used it is

***main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="244dp"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.85"
    android:contentDescription="@string/content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_label" />


</LinearLayout>
```

***mainactivity.java***

```
package com.pokemon.ash;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button button;
ImageView image;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    addButtonListener();
}

public void addButtonListener() {

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                //i am using all the image files name 
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.blastoise);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.bulbasaur);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.charizard);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.charmander);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.charmeleon);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ivysaur);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.squirtle);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.venusaur);
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.wartortle); 
                                    //but only last image is printing in the output I want all the images to be taken by drawable folder please help me in this such that i can swipe the images            
        }
    });
}}
```

[image]

Here only one image is printing correctly I want all the images to be seen such that when I swipe to left side it must go to the other image like *blastoise* image and swipe left it has to go to the *bulbasaur* image.

Comment: You can use **ViewPager** or **ViewFlipper** for that.

Comment: @Sandeep Check [this](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-as-image-slide-gallery-swipe-gallery/) example.

Comment: can u give the code snippet @PiyushGupta

Comment: thanks @PiyushGupta i will ask here if i get any doubt while working

Comment: thanks @Kunu if i need any help i will ask u pal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now your Button overrides the ImageResource of your 1 ImageView 9 times. That's the reason why you only see the last jpg. One ImageView can only hold one image. If you want to show 9 images you have to either use 9 ImageViews or you use a ViewPager (as @Piyush Gupta already suggested). Every Page of this ViewPager will have its own ImageView holding one of your 9 images. I think you wanna go with the ViewPager. More information about this here: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

On this link you find instructions on how to create a ViewPager with as many pages as you 
need:

```
Create an activity that does the following things:

 - Sets the content view to be the layout with the ViewPager.
 - Creates a class that extends the FragmentStatePagerAdapter 
   abstract class and implements the getItem() method 
   to supply instances of ScreenSlidePageFragment as new pages. 
 - The pager adapter also requires that you implement the getCount() method, 
   which returns the amount of pages the adapter will create (five in the example).
 - Hooks up the PagerAdapter to the ViewPager.
 - Handles the device's back button by moving backwards in the virtual stack of fragments. If the user is already on the first page, go back on the activity back stack.
```

Comment: thanks for your guidance pal if i get any error i will communicate with you

Comment: Sure, just post here. If my answer helped you out, please mark it as correct.

Comment: dude i have created one private array and passing all the images onto it like 6-7 images it is working fine i can swipe everything but instead of created an array and declaring statically the images can we declare dynamically such that i can find n number of images from drawable folder @muetzenflo

Comment: @Sandeep: Hi, I edited my answer and added a snippet from the link I gave you earlier. Please read first, try to understand and then ask again. Stackoverflow will not do your programming homework for you ;)

Comment: ya sure i did it but now i have different problem arise i used viewPager@muetzenflo